# How do I know if a button has been clicked after entry into a dropdown box that will also submit the form jquery mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to have a form where although the user has entered the dropdownbox which submits when focus is off: if they click the Clear button it will instead clear the form instead of saving the value.

JQuery:

```
  $("#clearbtn").click(function () {
        alert("clear clicked");
        $(this).data("clicked", true);
    });

    if ($("#clearbtn").data("clicked") == true) {
        this.form.submit();
    }
    else {
        $("#MainContent_ddlCountry").blur(function () {
            $("#MainContent_txtCountrySelected").val($(this).val());
            this.form.submit();
        });
    }
```

View:

```
<%  var qryCountry = from c in dbPCCommon.Country
               orderby c.CountryDescription ascending
               select new { c.CountryId, c.CountryDescription };

            ddlCountry.DataSource = qryCountry;
            ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryDescription";
            ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
            ddlCountry.SelectedValue = Model.CountryId.ToString();
            ddlCountry.DataBind();
%>
<tr>
<td class="labels">Country:</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server"  />
<%=Html.HiddenFor(a => Model.CountryId, new {@Value = ddlCountry.SelectedValue}) %>   
</td>                                   

</tr>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountrySelected" name = "txtCountrySelected" runat="server" />
```

However, every time I run this jQuery it keeps defaulting to the else statement. Or, am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Edit for clarification:
Let me try two scenarios.

Scenario 1: A user fills in information in a form for an address, and their cursor focus moves to the last dropdownbox for "Country". The idea here is once the user tabs off the Country box (or loses focus) it will submit the form and thus it will save. That works fine.

Scenario 2: Now, if a user fills in information and their cursor focus moves to the last dropdown for "Country" and they decide to clear out the entire form by clicking the "Clear" submit button on the screen. I want this to clear out the entire form instead of submitting the entry.

I thought that by using .blur where the focus is on the dropdown box, it doesn't lose focus when the user clicks the button and it should clear out the form, because the focus wasn't moved when the button was clicked. However, I am wrong.

Comment: please clarify your question

Comment: I added in a scenario, hope that helps.

Comment: Explain more about how the form gets submitted when a control loses focus. share the event handler for that?

Comment: Dave, I'm not sure what you would mean - the lines "this.form.submit" submits the form and the logic goes back to the controller. This code is from the corresponding view.

Comment: thats not a losing focus event, thats a click event. I'm even more confused.

Comment: Scenario 1 - user tabs into the Country dropdownbox, then tabs out of the dropdownbox (lose focus) -> this.form.submit. Scenario 2 - user tabs into the Country dropdownbox, then clicks the Clear button. However, the button click gets lost.

Comment: @silverwolf I edited my answer below. see if that works for ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution using a short timer delay to account for the click event:
It may not be the ideal solution, but it does work.

```
$("#clearbtn").click(function () {
    $(this).data("clicked", true);
});

function submitForm(e) {
    if ($("#clearbtn").data("clicked") !== true) {
        $("#MainContent_txtCountrySelected").val($("#MainContent_ddlCountry").val());
        alert("we are submitting!");
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("we are NOT submitting!");
    }
}

$("#MainContent_ddlCountry").blur(function () {
   setTimeout(submitForm,100);
});
```

Comment: This didn't work :( it doesn't fire the alert in the code block: `$("#clearbtn").click(function () {
        alert("clear clicked");
        $(this).data("clicked", true);
    });` it just goes straight to the if statement that you suggested.

Comment: @silvenwolf Event timing can be a bitch. You may have to consider handling the form submit logic a different way.

Comment: Thanks for this - turns out the user didn't want the clear button after all after asking for it for the last week or so. Gotta love users.